# Reset password email is showing up in my junk folder

Tags: symfony

I have recently setup `forgot password` functionality on my site using the stock symfony2 implementation.

Problem is my reset password email gets sent to my junk folder.

What causes this? Is it the content of the email itself?

Here it is:

```
Hello myemail@hotmail.com!
To reset your password - please visit http://application.mysite.com/resetting/reset/yLbv6BLD6ItSlmXSl4tFI7la78Es5UnS1GqvJnN_5uR

Regards,

the Team.
```

Could it be something in my settings?

Comment: no way to tell - maybe your email just look spammy, maybe your IP or IP block have shown up on spam blacklists. if nothing else, check the headers of the received mail - many spam filters will be scoring information there

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of possibilities that can cause this problem.

It's most often coming from the server (e-mail) configuration.
Look at the "original message" (with headers) to see if there is no explicit problem, but it's very difficult to debug.

Look at your email configuration (postfix local ? gmail ?), search for working examples and hopes you find the problem, especially if it's your production server.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There can be lot of reasons:

- you send emails from shared IP segment
- to low ammount of text in your message
- spammy look sender email address (for example "noreply@...")
- subject of message
- url thas point somwhere to testing environment (for example 127.0.0.1)

Try to change these, and experiment...